# ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to C++ (knew some a long time ago), and am flicking through 'Numerical Methods in Finance with C++' and I can't get one of the examples to work. It is very near the beginning of the book so shouldn't be difficult, but I am doing exactly what they are doing and am getting an error. I have looked through similar questions to this but I don't think I am making the same mistake as the other people (as many of them as I could be bothered to read). I have defined my functions in the BinModel cpp file, and just stated that they exist in the .h file, so I don't know why I am getting a duplication error? The whole compiling/running thing is a bit of a mystery to me, so if anyone knows where to find a really basic introduction to that stuff then that would be great as well. I am currently using Code::Blocks on my mac, I gave up on Xcode. Here is my code:

BinModel.01.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double RiskNeutProb(double U, double D, double R)
{
return (R-D)/(U-D);
}

double S(double S0, double U, double D, int n, int i)
{
return S0*pow(1+U,i)*pow(1+D,n-i);
}

int GetInputData(double& S0, double& U, double& D, double& R)
{
//entering data
cout << "Enter S0: "; cin >> S0;
cout << "Enter U: "; cin >> U;
cout << "Enter D: "; cin >> D;
cout << "Enter R: "; cin >> R;
cout << endl;

//check range
if (S0<=0.0 || U<=-1.0 || D<=-1.0 || U<=D || R<=-1.0)
{
    cout << "Illegal data ranges" << endl;
    cout << "terminating program" << endl;
    return 1;
}

//check arbitrage
if (R>=U || R<=D)
{
    cout << "Arbitrage exists" << endl;
    cout << "Terminating program" << endl;
    return 1;
}

cout << "Input data checked" << endl;
cout << "There is no arbitrage" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

BinModel01.h

```
#ifndef BinModel01_h
#define BinModel01_h

double RiskNeutProb(double U, double D, double R);

double S(double S0, double U, double D, int n, int i);

int GetInputData(double& S0, double& U, double& D, double& R);

#endif // BinModel01_h
```

And Main04.cpp

```
#include "BinModel01.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double S0,U,D,R;

if (GetInputData(S0,U,D,R)==1) return 1;

//compute risk neutral prob
cout << "q= " << RiskNeutProb(U,D,R) << endl;

//stock price at node n=3,i=2
int n=3; int i=2;
cout << "n= " << n << endl;
cout << "i= " << i << endl;
cout << "S(n,i)= " << S(S0,U,D,n,i) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

And the error:

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/Binomial obj/Debug/BinModel01.o obj/Debug/BinModel01.o obj/Debug/Main04.o obj/Debug/Main04.o   
duplicate symbol __Z12RiskNeutProbddd in:
    obj/Debug/BinModel01.o
duplicate symbol __Z1Sdddii in:
    obj/Debug/BinModel01.o
duplicate symbol __Z12GetInputDataRdS_S_S_ in:
    obj/Debug/BinModel01.o
duplicate symbol _main in:
    obj/Debug/Main04.o
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see  invocation)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I compiled everything separately and then I had them all in one project in Code:Blocks, so I just used the program to run and build that project, thinking that was the way to do it? Earlier I was using Xcode and just using the terminal to compile etc., but then I get a different error, but probably because I am not doing it correctly. Can anyone tell me how to the whole compiling/linking/running process using the terminal properly? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the replies. The project I made in Code::Blocks had extra .o files, but I have no idea where they came from. I will read around a bit more but perhaps it is easier to sort out my own Makefile and work out how to run these things through the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your linker command:

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/Binomial \
  obj/Debug/BinModel01.o \
  obj/Debug/BinModel01.o \
  obj/Debug/Main04.o \
  obj/Debug/Main04.o
```

It's linking the files twice over, so you're getting duplicates. The error will be in your Makefile, or whatever you're using to build.

Answer (score 2):

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/Binomial obj/Debug/BinModel01.o obj/Debug/BinModel01.o obj/Debug/Main04.o obj/Debug/Main04.o 
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You linked this object twice.

So, yeah, you're going to get duplicate symbol errors.

Answer (score 1):

`g++  -o bin/Debug/Binomial obj/Debug/BinModel01.o obj/Debug/BinModel01.o obj/Debug/Main04.o obj/Debug/Main04.o`

you shouldn't be linking in files twice.